# Istio Jaegar UI does not display services?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I did

```
helm install ibm-charts/ibm-istio --name=istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=true,kiali.enabled=true,tracing.enabled=true
```

I have a bunch of services e.g. `kubectl get svc` and was expecting to see some information about them in Jaegar dropdown, but I only see Istio-related ones. My services properly show up in tools like Grafana, etc.

Is there something extra I need to configure to see information about them in Jaegar?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below is an python snippet that can help you with traces. As @rinormaloku said you need to forward above headers to get span.

```
import sys

from flask import Flask, abort, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


def getForwardHeaders(request):
    headers = {}

    incoming_headers = [ 'x-request-id',
                         'x-b3-traceid',
                         'x-b3-spanid',
                         'x-b3-parentspanid',
                         'x-b3-sampled',
                         'x-b3-flags',
                         'x-ot-span-context'
    ]

    for ihdr in incoming_headers:
        val = request.headers.get(ihdr)
        if val is not None:
            headers[ihdr] = val
            print("incoming: "+ihdr+":"+val, file=sys.stderr)
    return headers


@app.route("/")
def f1():
    tracking_headers = getForwardHeaders(request)
    return requests.get('http://paytm-svc', headers=tracking_headers).content
```

Above snippet is working on istio in kubernetes.

If you are still getting any other errors, let me know.

Comment: Hi murarisumit, does "paytm-svc" service needs any special coding?

Comment: No, it's just a call to any third party service, you can make call to any other k8s service.

Answer (score 1):

The application needs to be instrumented to pass on the following headers:

```
x-request-id
x-b3-traceid
x-b3-spanid
x-b3-parentspanid
x-b3-sampled
x-b3-flags
x-ot-span-context
```

This is automated for most frameworks and implementations can be found in the [OpenTracing Contrib repository](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib). Besides that, for Pods and Services to be part of the service mesh, they need to fulfill the requirements specified [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/). Special attention to **named ports**.

BUT, as you are not getting any traces, it looks like a failure in setting up jaeger, sometimes uninstalling istio from your cluster and reinstalling fixes the issue.